# DateTime issue with $A.localizationService.formatDate()

Tags: aura

Need to clarify one doubt.

I have an apex code which converts DateTime from UTC into locale timezone using DateTime.format('MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a') method.
Here is the output (ET = Eastern Time).

UTC::2021-06-06 00:00:00 -->>
ET::06/05/2021 8:00 PM

UTC::2021-06-07 00:00:00 -->>
ET::06/06/2021 8:00 PM

The apex code is converting the UTC time correctly to the local timezone. But when I use
$A.localizationService.formatDateTime('2021-06-06T00:00:00.000Z', 'MM/dd/YYYY h:mm a');
The output is: 06/05/2021 7:00 PM

What is causing localization service to show incorrect date time, if anyone can shed some light, that will help my understanding.

Comment: Remember that Salesforce stores Datetime values in UTC but automatically converts them to current user's timezone for presentation purposes. I wonder if this is part of your issue. If you want some proper technical help here you will need to share a snippet of your code so we can see how you are doing the conversion, how you get the UTC value in the first place and how you present the result.

Comment: @PhilW Thank you for your comment. I do understand that SF converts UTC time into logged in users timezone. But it seems the localization service doesn't work the same way.

Comment: You need to add the specifics of what you are doing to give the community a chance to answer it.